# Using regex pattern variable with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, escaping, preg-match

I tried suggested solutions from other regex questions with preg_match but to no avail.

```
$match = '/^(.|a|an|and|the|this|at|in|or|of|is|for|to|its|as|by)\$/';
$filteredArray = array_filter($wordArray, function($x){
return !preg_match($match,$x);
});
```

It works when I include the string literal but I'd like to use a variable so I can add more words.  This version works:

```
$filteredArray = array_filter($wordArray, function($x){
return !preg_match("/^(.|a|an|and|the|this|at|in|or|of|is|for|to|its|as|by)$/",$x);
});
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Not sure if the solution but try to use double quoutes as in working example.

Comment: Ups, just got it. Its because of variable scope. Posting as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesnt work beause of the [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). You can't access variable $match from that function.

Solution in to use globals. They are accessible from everywhere.

```
$GLOBALS['word_regex'] = '/^(.|a|an|and|the|this|at|in|or|of|is|for|to|its|as|by)\$/';
$filteredArray = array_filter($wordArray, function($x){
return !preg_match($GLOBALS['word_regex'],$x);
});
```

That should work

Comment: Thank you very much Kristian.  Sorry to be a pain, but Amadan pointed out a much better option for adding new words which would be to use in_array.  I tried this but haven't gotten it to work.  Could you please point out what I'm doing wrong here:                                   $forbiddenWordsArray = array("a","an","the","this","at","in","or","of","is","for","to","its","as","by");
$filteredArray = array_filter($wordArray, function($x){
      return   !in_array($x,$forbiddenWordsArray);
    });

Comment: NVM! It was the same variable scope problem.

Comment: Replace all instances of `$forbiddenWordsArray` with `$GLOBALS['$forbiddenWordsArray']` and you should be done :)
And you would be pain in the ass, then ei wouldn't be in here:) NP

Comment: Globals are unnecessary; use a [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). Add a `use ($match)` to the anonymous function to access the variable (though the variable holding the pattern should be renamed; `$match` is usually used for the result of group capturing).

Answer (score 2):

Why regexp? Why not `!in_array($x, $forbiddenWordsArray)`? This way, easier to dynamically manage elements.

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous functions don't automatically capture variables from the enclosing scope. You'll need to explicitly do this using a `use` declaration:

```
$shortWords = '/^(.|a|an|and|the|this|at|in|or|of|is|for|to|its|as|by)\$/';
$filteredArray = array_filter($wordArray, 
                              function($x) use ($shortWords) {
                                  return !preg_match($shortWords,$x);
                              });
```